# Updating data using dynamically generating rows and a static section

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, dynamic, dynamic-vf-component

I have two section in which one is dynamically updated rows... I need top create cases using the first section and each row of the dynamic rows generated. I have used the following code but I am not able to save the records. Please suggest.

```
public class DynamicRows
{
    public list<Order__C> orderList{get;set;}
    public list<Orderwrapper> orderwrapperList{get;set;}
    public Order__C orderObj;
    public Integer counter{get;set;}

     public DynamicRows(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
     {
       String sql = 'SELECT Name, Product__c, Quantity__c, Packaging__c,Case__c, Order_Description__c, Exchanged_Through__c, Order_Cancelled__c   FROM Order__c';
        orderList = Database.Query(sql);

          orderObj = (Order__C)controller.getRecord();

         counter = 0;
           orderList= new list<Order__C>(); 
           orderwrapperList= new list<Orderwrapper>();
           for(Integer i=0;i<1;i++){
               Orderwrapper ordWrap = new Orderwrapper(new Order__C()); 
               counter++;
               ordWrap.counterWrap = counter;
               orderwrapperList.add(ordWrap); 

           }

     }
 /*    
   public void AddRow()
    {
        memberAddList.add(new Order__c());

    }  

    public void RemoveRow()
    {
      //  memberAddList.remove(new Order__c());
    }  
    */

      public PageReference addRow(){

        Orderwrapper ordWrap = new Orderwrapper(new Order__C()); 

        counter++;
        ordWrap.counterWrap = counter; 
        orderwrapperList.add(ordWrap); 
        return null;    
    }
    public PageReference removingRow(){

        Integer param = Integer.valueOf(Apexpages.currentpage().getParameters().get('index'));

        for(Integer i=0;i<orderwrapperList.size();i++){
            if(orderwrapperList[i].counterWrap == param ){
                orderwrapperList.remove(i);     
            }
        }

        counter--;
        return null;    
    }

    public PageReference saving(){
        list<Order__C> updateOrderList;
        updateOrderList= new list<Order__C>();
        if(!updateOrderList.isEmpty()){
            for(Orderwrapper orderWrapper:orderwrapperList){
                updateOrderList.add(orderWrapper.order);
            }
        }
        if(!updateOrderList.isEmpty()){
            upsert updateOrderList;
        }
       ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Info,'Record Saved Successfully.');
       ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg); 
       return (new ApexPages.StandardController(orderObj )).view();
    }

    public class Orderwrapper{
        public Order__C order{get;set;}
        public Integer counterWrap{get;set;}

        public Orderwrapper(Order__C ord){
            this.order = ord;  

        }
    } 

}




<apex:page standardController="Order__c" extensions="DynamicRows">
   <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock title="Orders">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Order Details">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Order__c.Case__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Order__c.Name}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Order__c.Order_Description__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Order__c.Exchanged_Through__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Order__c.Order_Cancelled__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
             <apex:pageBlockSection title="Add Products">
              <apex:pageBlock title=" Products List ">
                <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
                <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Add Row" action="{!addRow}" reRender="table" immediate="true"/>
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!orderwrapperList}" var="page" id="table"> 
                    <apex:column headerValue="Product">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!page.order.Product__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Quantity">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!page.order.Quantity__c}" />
                    </apex:column>
                     <apex:column headerValue="Packaging">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!page.order.Packaging__c}" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Action">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Delete" action="{!removingRow}" immediate="true">
                            <apex:param name="index" value="{!page.counterWrap}"/>  
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saving}" />            
        </apex:pageBlock>      
        </apex:pageblockSection>        
        <apex:pageblockSection columns="1" >
            <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" />
            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>         
        </apex:pageblockSection>
       </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is why saving doesn't work, then this might be the answer.

In the method 'saving', you create an empty list.

```
list<Order__C> updateOrderList;
updateOrderList= new list<Order__C>();
```

The problem is the part below. If the created list is NOT empty, then the orderWrappers will be added to the list to be insert/update later. But the updateOrderList is always empty, hence, nothing will be added to updateOrderList.

```
if(!updateOrderList.isEmpty()){
 for(Orderwrapper orderWrapper:orderwrapperList){
            updateOrderList.add(orderWrapper.order);
 }
}
if(!updateOrderList.isEmpty()){
    upsert updateOrderList;
}
```

I think you wanted to do this:

```
if(!orderwrapperList.isEmpty()){
 for(Orderwrapper orderWrapper:orderwrapperList){
            updateOrderList.add(orderWrapper.order);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

+1 to lw29's answer, but just want to make this point...

When writing code that loops there is no need to also have `isEmpty` checks because the loop just never gets entered anyway. And while older code examples have `isEmpty` checks before insert/update/upsert calls, that is not necessary either as a zero length argument results in the call to the database being skipped.

Less lines of code means less chance of introducing bugs:

```
list<Order__C> updateOrderList = new list<Order__C>();
for(Orderwrapper orderWrapper : orderwrapperList){
    updateOrderList.add(orderWrapper.order);
}
upsert updateOrderList;
```